# Google calendar:How can i get notifications when a calendar event its added

Tags: notifications, google-calendar-api

I would like to get notifications from Google Calendar on my phone when someone edits or adds an event to a calender that my work uses. How can i enable that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on a calendar you want notifications about, select Settings.  You can manage email notifications at the bottom of the Calendars tab, and you can set up SMS under the Mobile Setup tab.